# Need to pass arguments to docker entrypoint.sh during each docker start ( not docker run ). Is something like this possiable?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i have a dockerfile , i can give enviroment variables & arguments during 'docker run' and it is persistance during docker start/stop/restart.
But sometimes i many need to change it, which requires me to make a new container everytime.
Is there a solution to it ?

Comment: better to post your dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

There are many properties of a container that can only be set at creation time, and the environment variables and command line are among those.  You must delete and recreate the container to change these.  There isn't a workaround.

If you're just concerned about the length of the `docker run` command, consider either packaging that command in a shell script or looking at an orchestration tool like Docker Compose.  If you change a setting in a `docker-compose.yml` file and re-run `docker-compose up -d`, it will make the minimal change required for that (which could include deleting and recreating the container, but it won't touch containers whose current settings are fine).